# The model from Keras give me same output

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm trained a model in Keras, only Dense layers. However, when i try to predict it gives me the same answer all the time even with different values.

```
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
tf.python.control_flow_ops = tf

df = pd.read_csv('/home/sam/Documents/data.csv')
dfX = df[['Close']]
dfY = df[['Y']]
bobX = dfX.as_matrix()
boby = dfY.as_matrix()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(200, input_dim=1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(75))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1))
adam = Adam(lr=0.1)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer= adam)
print(model.summary())

model.fit(bobX, boby, nb_epoch=2500, batch_size=500, verbose=0)

model.predict(np.array([[210.99]]))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your learning rate is WAY to high for Adam.  Actually 0.1 is too high for most optimizers I have used.  You should use 1e-3 or 1e-4 as the learning rate.  These usually work well for me.  When you use that high of a learning rate the model will fail to converge.  From my experience it often just settles for the constant average value of the problem.

Comment: so do i set it to lr = 0.03, sorry about that im new to keras

Comment: 1e-3 means 1*10^-3 = 0.001

Comment: Also you probably don't need such a large batch size.  Use something like 32/64.  Also you probably don't need 2500 epochs.  You should watch it train and stop it when the loss on the validation stop decreasing.  Finally you also probably don't need 4 layers.  I would start with just one hidden layer.

Comment: excuse me does number of epochs affect in this problem as my training dataset is around 87000 and testing is 45000 images and i used one epoch but got different values with same output